# Serialize Xml to Json using type attribute in c#

Tags: c#, json, xmlserializer

I would like to serialize my xml in a json keeping the number type.

Below my XML:

```
<root type="number">42</root>
```

Here my expected result:

```
{
"root": 42
}
```

I'm trying to use the Newtonsoft Library, using JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode method but seems that doesn't work:

MY CODE:

```
XmlDocument dox1 = new XmlDocument();
string xx = "<root type=\"number\">42</root>";
dox1.LoadXml(xx);

string JsonContent = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(dox1, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, true);
//JsonResult json = Json(JsonContent);
return JsonContent;
```

THE RESULT:

```
{
"@type": "number",
"#text": "42"
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: In XML there is only strings (XSD changes that, but I've no idea if JSON.NET's XML supports XSD). For anything other than simple cases you really need to write code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML doesn't have any relevance to your expected JSON. It is totally a manual conversion which you might do like (I assume you meant 42, else explain the logic getting 4):

```
void Main()
{
    string xx = "<root type=\"number\">42</root>";
    var value = new { orderType = (int)XElement.Parse(xx)};
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

Comment: Anyway thank you, you open my mind :) i'll use your way to personalize dynamically my parsing watching at the type format in my xml