# Convert XML to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

I have an XML and when converting to JSON, all the values became string as below:

```
XML:
<root><deviceToEgressLocationDistance>600</deviceToEgressLocationDistance></root>
```

```
JSON:
{ "deviceToEgressLocationDistance": "600" }
```

while it should be

```
JSON:
{ "deviceToEgressLocationDistance": 600 }
```

below the code I am using but it converts everything to strings

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
string jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Formatting.Indented, true);
```

I have checked the solution in
[Serialize Xml to Json using type attribute in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779583/serialize-xml-to-json-using-type-attribute-in-c-sharp)

but I cannot manually parse every value as the xml file properties are changing every time so the next time it could be

```
XML:
<root><Location1>500.88</Location1><Location2>650</Location2></root>
```

The xml could have any structure including nesting properties.

Any ideas?

Update: After converting the XML to JSON, this JSON file is going to be the source to another system and if the JSON file has the wrong types like treating numbers as string or even DateTime as string, the subsystem fail to process the input source. So, I need to preserve the types in XML when converting to JSON

Comment: Deserialize this into an object model which has `int deviceToEgressLocationDistance;` and the re-serialize as JSON

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert JSON to XML or XML to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json)

Comment: No, They are using the exact code in my question. it does not solve the type issue

Comment: You have to do it like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911325/convert-xml-string-to-c-sharp-object). First, convert XML to Object. You need to define class for this object. Later, convert object to JSON.

Comment: @ahmetgül as I mentioned in my question, I do not have a schema. the file structure is changing so I cannot really convert to an object since I won't have a class to convert to.

Comment: Hey, in that case you can create a class which contains all kind of attribute, In your testing, when you see a new property, add it to your class. I am pretty sure that those who prepare the XML send with specific schema.